# why doesn't Tomcat 7x require WSServletContextListener and WSServlet configured in web.xml for Jax-ws service deployment?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat7, jax-ws, tomcat6

I'm deploying and testing  a simple `Jax-ws service` in both `Tomcat6x` and `Tomcat7x` with the `jaxws-ri-2.2.8` added to both the server lib directories .
`Tomcat6x` requires the `WSServletContextListener` and `WSServlet`  and configured in `web.xml` whereas in `Tomcat 7x` the webservices gets deployed without the `WSServletContextListener` and `WSServlet` configuration. 
Whats different in `Tomcat7` that makes the `web.xml` configuration optional?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Tomcat 7.x and Servlet 3.0, the listener `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener` is dynamically loaded. Since Java EE 6, a new component was added: [**`javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html)

> Interface which allows a library/runtime to be notified of a web application's startup phase and perform any required **programmatic registration** of servlets, filters, and **listeners** in response to it.

The file jaxws-rt.jar contains in `\META-INF\services` a simple file text named `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` with one line:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer
```

This is the fully qualified class name which loads the required listener.

See also [*Using Servlets 3.0 ServletContainerInitializer*](http://piotrnowicki.com/2011/03/using-servlets-3-0-servletcontainerinitializer/).

Comment: Thanks very Much Paul. This answer clears a lot of questions of mine, though i have a question regarding the URL mapping.If we do not have a WSServlet to map a url-pattern , are all the requests verified against the url-patterns configured against the endpoints in the sun-jaxws.xml file ?

Comment: If you see the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.ws/servlet/2.2.8/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/servlet/WSServletContainerInitializer.java#WSServletContainerInitializer), you will find that the file `sun-jaxws.xml` is loaded as if you'd configured it in the normal way..

Comment: I did see the code where the sun-jaxws.xml is being loaded but failed to notice the method                                  `private void registerWSServlet(List<ServletAdapter> adapters, ServletContext context)`                                        which registers a WsServlet dynamically if there are any unregistered URL patterns. Thanks Paul

Comment: This is configured without a path prefix. The services' mappings (actually, for the servlet) are taken from the configuration file.  If the `sun-jaxws.xml` does not have endpoints, the servlet is not added.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 7 supports Servlet 3.0 that enables annotations to be used to configure various components of a web application including Servlets and Listeners.